# Redirection and replacement with Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am having trouble getting this to work in nginx:

I am trying to rewrite, a url string like this to this:

```
http://domainname/n/xxx = > http://domaindomain/x/xxx
```

I would like only "n" to change to "x"

I have tried :

```
location  /n/ {
    rewrite ^/n/(.*)$ /x/? last;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: In your example you change domain name this could be done only with redirect. But in your code I see rewrite. What of this do you want?

Comment: I do not want the domainname to change, we want to change url schema after domain name eg.

   http://domainname.com/keyword/123 to http://domainname/new_keyword/123

Comment: Do you want user to see `new_keyword`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following rule:

```
rewrite ^/n/(.*)$ /x/$1 permanent;
```

`(.*)` will capture your URL after the `/n/` part and `$1` will place the same thing in the target URL.

Using the `permanent` keyword will redirect the users with a 301 HTTP status code